# ant, recursive copying specific files in directory

Tags: ant

I have some structure like this:

```
-Dir A
-Dir B
-config
|---subdir1
    |-------config.dist
|---subdir2
    |--------default.dist
    |--------db.dist
```

I need to copy all the *.dist files to the same directory cuting '.dist'
Is it possible do it via ant?
I would like to do it recursive.

Comment: Copy just the files, flattening the source directory structure, or with the directory structure?

Comment: With directory structure.
For example: in directory subdir1 I should have files: config.dist and config

Comment: Sounds like http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<copy todir="${dir}">
  <fileset dir="${dir}">
    <include name="**/*.dist"/>
  </fileset>
  <regexpmapper from="(.*)\.dist" to="\1"/>
</copy>
```